# Bootstrap carousel controls not working on firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, carousel

i have this simple carousel here is the html markup

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/clinic1.jpg" alt="first slide">
      </a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/clinic2.jpg" alt="secound slide">
      </a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/clinic3.jpg" alt="third slide">
      </a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

the problem is with the carousel controls , it is working just fine on chrome but when i tried it on firefox the control arrows are not clickable , the glyphicons appears just fine but they do not function , the automated sliding is working fine but when i try to manually change slides the controls arrows not working.

Comment: Try moving the `col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1` classes outside of the `<div class="carousel">` itself.

Comment: @cvrebert sorry for late reply , i tried it and yet same problem

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out . i have changed the css for the caption some how this made the caption on top of everything on firefox so the navigation was not working because i have been clicking on the caption all the time. I still did not figure why this happened on firefox only.